# Python's pyplot.scatter and numpy.arctan will produce the wrong figure

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

I want to plot the scatter plot in Python.
The correct code is as follow:

```
    import numpy as np
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
    n=1000
    x=np.random.randn(n,1)
    y=np.random.randn(n,1)
    color_xy=np.arctan2(y,x)

    plt.scatter(x,y,s=75,c=color_xy,alpha=0.5)
```

And the result is as follow:

[image]

But if I change the code

```
    color_xy=np.arctan2(y,x)
```

to

```
    color_xy=np.arctan(y,x)
```

It will produce a wrong figure as follow:

[image]

But the parameter "c" controls the color. Isn't it?

PS: The following code also produces the wrong figure.

```
plt.scatter(x,y,s=75,alpha=0.5)
```

Comment: The difference between `numpy.arctan` and `numpy.arctan2` is first of all that

[`numpy.arctan`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.14.0/reference/generated/numpy.arctan.html) takes the ratio between the legs (or catheti) as argument, 

    `numpy.arctan(y/x)` 
     while
[`numpy.arctan2`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.14.0/reference/generated/numpy.arctan2.html#numpy.arctan2) takes the the legs as individual arguments,

        `numpy.arctan(y,x)`

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you are right, c is just to control colors. Please look at the documentation of [numpy.arctan](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.14.0/reference/generated/numpy.arctan.html). It is changing x to arctan of y, as opposed to [numpy.arctan2](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.14.0/reference/generated/numpy.arctan2.html) calculates element wise arctan of x1/x2, and does not modify x or y. So once you call

```
color_xy=np.arctan(y,x)
```

you have changed your x, and obviously, you will see a different graph

Comment: @錢冠邑 If this solved your problem, please [accept the answer.](https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer)